# Python code that finds total pay monthly. Phrased very weirdly

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Write a function that calculates a total amount of money a worker has made when given the initial salary (per month) and months worked. Every year the worker is at the job, their salary increases by $100 per month.

Please try to keep the level of code relatively low. And I know that the phrasing is pretty weird but I believe it is every month after your first year you make 100 dollars more so if your start per month is 1,000 then your 13th month is 1,100, a jump of 100 and your 14th month is 1,300, a jump of 200 from last months, next month is a jump of 300 and so on and so forth.

```
def calculate_pay(initial_salary, months_worked):
    if months_worked <= 12:
        tots = initial_salary * months_worked
        return tots
    else:
        after_first = months_worked - 12
        total_bonus = 0
        for i in range(after_first):
            tips = i * after_first
            total_bonus += tips
        baseline = initial_salary * months_worked
        final = baseline + total_bonus
        return final
    
    
print(calculate_pay(1000, 24))
```

Here's my code, it doesn't work for anything more than 12 months at the company. It is relatively close to the expected answer each time but there is no relation between the differences.

Comment: typo: ```i*afterfirst```  should be ```i*100```

Comment: I’d expect the first 12 months would be 1000 x 12, then the next 12 months would be 1100 x 12, etc. Not a raise every month after 12.  If you have sample inputs and outputs, you should provide them

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this using the formula for the [sum of triangle numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2435816/a-formula-for-the-sum-of-the-triangular-numbers).

```
def calculate_pay(initial_salary, months_worked):
    base_line, tips = initial_salary * months_worked, 0
    if (after_first := months_worked - 12) > 0:
        tips = 100 * (after_first * (after_first+1) * (after_first+2) // 6)
    return base_line + tips
        
print(calculate_pay(1000, 24))
```

Output

```
60400
```